# Why does cifs share show as used disk space on client

Tags: linux, fstab, cifs

I have mounted a CIFS share on a Linux client machine.

IF I copy 100MB of data onto the server, the client shows a drop of 100MB in disk space.

Are the files on the server replicated to the client? and if so, does that mean I can only mount a CIFS share if I have enough space on the client to hold all the servers files?

Just to clarify why I was worrying about this. When I ran DF -h I got the following result

```
│Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2                             4.1T  1.7G  3.9T   1% /
```

After copying 100MB of data onto the server I got this result.

```
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/md2                             4.1T  1.8G  3.9T   1% /
```

What will hapen when the server has more than 4.1TB of data on it. Will I show a used space in excess of the local disks Size?

Comment: Are you sure the share is, in fact, mounted? Also, do you have `cachefilesd` running?

Comment: cachefilesd not running and yes the share was mounted. I actually added the files on a windows client that had the same share mounted. The funny thing is, webmin showed the disk usage as not being changed. So I am assuming it is something specific to the DF command.